# Import and use a class from a jar using Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to implement hoptoad in my existing maven project. I ve given the following lines in pom.xml as suggested in http://code.google.com/p/hoptoad/

```
<project>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>hoptoad-repository</id>
      <name>Hoptoad Repository</name>
      <url>http://hoptoad.googlecode.com/svn/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>code.lucamarrocco</groupId>
      <artifactId>hoptoad-notifier</artifactId>
      <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

When i try to use the `HoptoadNotice` in my catch block, i m getting `ClassNotFoundException`. I am using Eclipse IDE. I am not able to figure out, that the problem is because of inclusion of this code(in pom) or in the IDE. I can understand that the inclusion of these lines alone do not help the code to recognize the jar. So, i tried installing the jar in maven repository. But still it did not help.

Note:- I have not just blindly copied as shown above, directly into the pom.xml. I have included the lines of code wrt `<dependencies>` and `<repositories>` blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maven configuration looks correct.

Make sure that the `hoptoad-notifier-1.8.jar` is correct deployed.

For an standalone app, this means for example specified in the argument list or the manifiest.
For an web app, it means the jar is copied (by maven, not by you) in the libs folder.

Comment: The error got solved. I have done the changes in the wrong pom.xml. This project is comprised of many sub-projects. I ve included these pom changes in one of the sub-project and hence it worked. Previously i made changes in the main pom.xml. BTW, thanks for responding.